# How are compasses influenced by a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I found this diagram in Pearson Physics 2009:

[image]

I don't quite understand the reasoning for the directions of the compasses. I understand that mechanically, compasses are supposed to point north. But at the "equator" (for lack of a better word) of the magnet, the two compasses point, on the compass, north, but in relation to the magnet, south. Why is this?

I'm just having a difficult time wrapping my head around this diagram.

Comment: Does [this help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet#Polarity) ? The physics book is correct as every needle is a magnet in itself. When you go hiking your compass needle is painted such that its "south pole" points north as it must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like magnetic poles repel, and unlike magnetic poles attract
each other. Therefore the north pole of the compass needle points
to the south pole of the bar magnet, and vice versa.

But actually this wording is still somewhat too short.
More precisely saying, the compass needle will line up with the
magnetic field lines produced by the bar magnet.
These magnetic field lines  come out from the north pole
of the bar magnet, take a turn, and finally reenter at its south pole.

[image]
(image from [Hyperphysics - Bar magnet](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/elemag.html#c1))

Now you may still be confused by the behavior of a compass
in the magnetic field of the earth. The north pole of the
compass needle points to the north pole of the earth. After
all this is the historical reason why this pole of the
compass needle is called its north pole.
See also [Wikipedia - Earth's magnetic field - Magnetic poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field#Magnetic_poles).
So in the *geographic* north of the earth there is actually
the *magnetic* south pole, and vice versa.